# cannot clear form field with functional react hook in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

The code below works fine by submit a post message. now i want to clear the message input form on form submission but cannot get it to work. I have tried the following 3 options but yet no luck.

**1.)**

```
 function clearState() {
        message('');

    }
// pass the clear state function on form submission
clearState();
```

**2.) Clear form by referencing the form id**

```
document.getElementById('my_form').reset();
```

**3.) using event target reset**

```
event.target.reset();
```

**here is the full code.**

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";


export default function App(props) {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  const currentDate = new Date();

  useEffect(() => {
    // fetch content axio or ajax
  }, []);

 function clearState() {
        message('');

    }

  function handleChange(event) {
    setMessage(event.target.value);
  }

  function handleSubmit(event) {;
    event.preventDefault();
    const newMessages = messages;
    const data = { message: message, date: new Date() };
    setMessages(newMessages.concat([data]));

//clear all form field based on form id
clearState();
//document.getElementById('my_form').reset();
//event.target.reset();


  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>


      <div className="chat_container">
        {messages.map((m, e) => (
          <div key={e}>
            <div className="chat_message">
              chat: {m.message} ---{m.date.toLocaleTimeString()}
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}

      </div>

      <div className="myFooter">
        <form id"my_form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Name:
            <input type="text" value={message} onChange={handleChange} />
          </label>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: it should be `setMessage("") ` instead of `message("") ` in the clearState fn

Comment: Voting to close as typo; should use `setMessage` to update the message value.

Comment: Thanks alot everyone. its working now